# Django: why does a form's clean_<fieldname> method require you to access cleaned_data?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using the [clean_fieldname](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) method on my Django forms:

```
def clean_recipients(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['recipients']
    ...
```

Is there a reason Django can't simply provide this value as an argument?

```
def clean_recipients(self, data):
    ...
```

(I am thinking of writing a wrapper that will do it they way I want, since I'm cleaning many fields and it is getting a bit repetitive to type that line every time.)

Comment: Hmm. I think that accessing `cleaned_data` through `self` is actually cleaner than passing it as an argument, and it's one less parameter I have to remember.

Comment: Because you might need a field to check another fields data? For flexibility? Because cleaned_data already exists? Because you might not even use cleaned_data? I'd try to stick to convention as much as possible - that one line is not difficult. Your call though!

Comment: There was a great deal of discussion about that when Adrian was first implementing what was then newforms. You can probably find it by digging back through the django-developers user list.

Comment: FWIW If you write the same `clean_xxx` methods again and again it might be time to read the doc for fields validators and/or custom fields... The `clean_xxx` methods are really here for one-off processing.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Thanks. My validation requires accessing instance data, but field validators and custom fields do not let me do that.